# Drop first packet with iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, udp, attacks

Our servers are getting UDP-flood spoofed ip attacks. I think, we can solve this problem with iptables and i want to make a rule with iptables.

When a ip tried to send a udp packet, iptables will block this. And after this first packet, for 10 secs. other packets will be accept.

How can i make this with iptables?

Comment: Please, post your current iptables rules.

Comment: I haven't any iptables rule now..

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp [--dport 12345] -m recent --name attack --set
iptables -A INPUT -p udp [--dport 12345] -m recent --name attack --rcheck --seconds 10 --hitcount 2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp [--dport 12345] -j DROP
```

This should permit the second and subsequent packets from any given address in a rolling ten-second window; others will be DROPped.  As usual, getting them in the right place in your existing ruleset is both vitally important and your problem.  If you aren't restricting this by port, make very sure you don't lock out DNS responses (and other udp-based responses you may consider desirable).